# Android, How to Remove "NullPointerException" coming in onClick method

Tags: android

Here i wrote some code, and i want to call a method of other class from onClick() and getting NPE in "new Start().moreApplication(feedsId);" line..

```
        final TextView feeds=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.more_feeds);
    feeds.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Log.e("MoreChoices","onclick---------");
            final int feedsId= feeds.getId();
            Log.e("MoreChoices","onclick----After initialization of id--------");
            new Start().moreApplication(feedsId);
            Log.e("MoreChoices","onclick----------------After calling--------");
        }
    });
```

Start.java is my an other Activity class, and i have one in Start.java, and i want to call that method from other class with using this code..

Please tell why i am getting NPE in 
"new Start().moreApplication(feedsId);"
line...

Thanks in Advance please guide me....

Comment: Show the exact logcat exception stack trace for this.

Comment: are you trying to open new activity? can you show the listing of Start.java?

Comment: Don't create activities by calling their constructor. Use the [startActivity method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Please, take some time reading [anddev book](http://andbook.anddev.org/), a very good place to start android development.

Read pages 50+ and you will understand that your not doing the right thing to create activities and pass data from one to another.

You should

- startActivity by using either an intent or the class of this activity
- pass data from your activity to the new one using intent's extra parameters.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

final TextView feeds=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.more_feeds);

by

final TextView feeds=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.more_feeds);

I hope you got solution .

Comment: send me a log of this exception

Answer (score 0):

I think u need to get the View ID which u have clicked the enhanced code look like

```
final TextView feeds=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.more_feeds);
feeds.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Log.e("MoreChoices","onclick---------");
        final int feedsId= arg0.getId();
        Log.e("MoreChoices","onclick----After initialization of id--------");
        new Start().moreApplication(feedsId);
        Log.e("MoreChoices","onclick----------------After calling--------");
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry, i need TextView ID that are going properly, but exception is coming when i create the object of Start.java class and calling the method of Strat.java class with using reference of Start.java class..